# Add all dates between two in a column through excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a form where the user will input the start and end date. With this date, I need to enter all the dates from start date to end date in another worksheet `DailyData`. I am using below code but somehow it's not working. The code is not giving any error as well.How to make it work

```
Sub day()

Dim MaxGain As Workbook
Dim Main As Worksheet
Dim DailyData As Worksheet

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim i As Long


Set MaxGain = Excel.Workbooks("MaxGain.xlsm")
Set Main = MaxGain.Worksheets("Main")
Set DailyData = MaxGain.Worksheets("DailyData")

StartDate = Main.Range("B5").Value
EndDate = Main.Range("B6").Value

i = 1
  For DateLooper = StartDate To EndDate 

     DailyData.Cells(i, "A") = DateLooper

     i = i + 1
  Next DateLooper


End Sub
```

Comment: you never dim DateLooper. But you also dim i? Arent they being used for the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub day()
    Dim MaxGain As Workbook
    Dim Main As Worksheet
    Dim DailyData As Worksheet
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, newDate as date
    Dim i As Long, DaysBetween as long

    Set MaxGain = Excel.Workbooks("MaxGain.xlsm")
    Set Main = MaxGain.Worksheets("Main")
    Set DailyData = MaxGain.Worksheets("DailyData")
    StartDate = Main.Range("B5").Value
    EndDate = Main.Range("B6").Value
    DaysBetween = DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
    newDate = StartDate
    for i = 1 to DaysBetween
        DailyData.Cells(i, "A") = newDate
        newDate = DateAdd ("d", 1, newDate)

    next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: its starting the date from actual Startdate+1. How can I include the start date as well ?

Comment: edited to show you how. Just swap the position of the date chage/write lines

Answer (score 3):

Excel has few methods of creating series in the Home tab > Editing > Fill

```
Sub Day()
    [DailyData!A1] = [Main!B5].Value
    [DailyData!A:A].DataSeries Stop:=[Main!B6]
End Sub
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-dataseries-method-excel

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `DateLooper` as :

```
Dim DateLooper As Long
```

Then in your `For Loop` :

```
DailyData.Cells(i, "A") = StartDate + DateLooper
```